# Apps installing in teams in MS Teams not working as expected

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a published application in the Microsoft App store.

Before heading towards the issue, explain below how it works when the app is installed in the team. So, when the bot/app is added to the team it sends a proactive welcome message inside the team. Below is the code which is responsible for this:

```
constructor() {
        super();

        this.onConversationUpdate(async (handler) => {
            let activity = handler._activity;

            if (activity.membersAdded) {
                if (activity.membersAdded[0].id.includes(process.env.MicrosoftAppId)) {
                   // Send proactive welcome message
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> Keeping in mind when the app is installed/added to a team, definitely there should be **handler** data with me.

That's the case and it's working fine all over tested in different tenants as well, everything working fine.

But, in one of the tenants, there are 3-4 teams,  Installing/adding the app doesn’t trigger the constructor at all. Not even a single log is getting there for me. Strangely, inside the manage team` - App section, I could see the app.

Not sure if is it a bug in MS Teams.

Comment: Has the bot been installed previously into that team/channel?

Comment: No, the bot wasn’t installed previously.

Comment: Can you please check for this tenant permissions and azure BOT with other tenants?

Comment: Hello @GauravGupta - Can you please ask them to share the console logs either from Teams web client or Desktop ? Refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: Also, is it working for other teams in that same tenant ?